Spring Authorization Server requirements
We have a project that uses the deprecated Spring Security OAuth module.
We also use Spring v5, Spring Boot v2 and Tomcat v9. Java version is 17.
From what I have found the new Spring Authorization Server is based on Spring Security 6.0, which is based off of Spring Framework 6.0 and require a minimum of Java 17 at runtime, as well as a minimum of Tomcat 10 or Jetty 11.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/28/spring-authorization-server-is-going-1-0
Does it mean, that Spring Authorization Server REQUIRES Spring v6 on the classpath? And it will not work in out project? I am not sure how to understand the above sentence from spring.io.
But in the official docs there is only info that Spring Authorization Server requires a Java 17 or higher Runtime Environment.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html
I assume that we cannot migrate to the new Spring Authorization Server as it is based on Spring v6. Is that correct?

If you can separate the authorization server part of your old apllication, then you could use it. If you need to have authirzation server and OAuth2 cient in the same Spring Boot application, you cannot use it.

@dur Can you elaborate more on that? What is the reason?
We have everything as one application, there are 3 classes:


class AuthorizationConf extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter annotated with EnableAuthorizationServer


class WebSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter annotated with EnableWebSecurity


class ResourceServerConf extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter annotated with EnableResourceServer


